# colcon build moveit2 failure because of moveit_ros_warehouse collect2 error

Tags: ros, ros2, moveit, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm building moveit2 from this tutorial: moveit2_tutorials.picknik.ai/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and my ros2 version is foxy, which was built from debian.
Rosdep returns all rosdeps installed successfully and moveit2's repos have been successfully cloned.

I'm getting this when building:

--- stderr: moveit_ros_warehouse
/usr/bin/ld: libmoveit_warehouse.so.: undefined reference to `MD5'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is the code from colcon build:

> :~/robotics/moveo_ws/ws$ colcon build --event-handlers desktop_notification- status- >--cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
>
> Starting >>> geometric_shapes
> [Processing: geometric_shapes]
> [Processing: geometric_shapes]
> [Processing: geometric_shapes]
> [Processing: geometric_shapes]
> Finished <<< geometric_shapes [2min 1s]
> Starting >>> moveit_msgs
> Finished <<< moveit_msgs [7.18s]
> Starting >>> srdfdom
> Finished <<< srdfdom [0.52s]
> Starting >>> moveit_common
> Finished <<< moveit_common [0.27s]
> Starting >>> controller_manager_msgs
> Finished <<< controller_manager_msgs [2.03s]
> Starting >>> ros2_control_test_assets
> Finished <<< ros2_control_test_assets [0.25s]
> Starting >>> hardware_interface
> Finished <<< hardware_interface [0.98s]
> Starting >>> controller_interface
> Finished <<< controller_interface [0.66s]
> Starting >>> controller_manager
> Finished <<< controller_manager [1.18s]
> Starting >>> warehouse_ros
> Finished <<< warehouse_ros [0.45s]
> Starting >>> moveit_resources_panda_description
> Finished <<< moveit_resources_panda_description [0.26s]
> Starting >>> moveit_resources_panda_moveit_config
> Finished <<< moveit_resources_panda_moveit_config [0.28s]
> Starting >>> moveit_resources_fanuc_description
> Finished <<< moveit_resources_fanuc_description [0.26s]
> Starting >>> moveit_resources_fanuc_moveit_config
> Finished <<< moveit_resources_fanuc_moveit_config [0.27s]
> Starting >>> forward_command_controller
> Finished <<< forward_command_controller [0.63s]
> Starting >>> moveit_resources_pr2_description
> Finished <<< moveit_resources_pr2_description [0.30s]
> Starting >>> moveit_core
> Finished <<< moveit_core [4.59s]
> Starting >>> moveit_ros_occupancy_map_monitor
> Finished <<< moveit_ros_occupancy_map_monitor [0.48s]
> Starting >>> moveit_ros_planning
> Finished <<< moveit_ros_planning [2.06s]
> Starting >>> moveit_kinematics
> Finished <<< moveit_kinematics [0.98s]
> Starting >>> moveit_ros_warehouse
> --- stderr: moveit_ros_warehouse
> /usr/bin/ld: libmoveit_warehouse.so.: undefined reference to `MD5'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[2]: *** [warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse_broadcast.dir/build.make:346:
> warehouse/moveit_warehouse_broadcast] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:189: warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse_broadcast.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
>
> Failed   <<< moveit_ros_warehouse [1.37s, exited with code 2]
>
> Summary: 20 packages finished [2min 27s]
> 1 package failed: moveit_ros_warehouse
> 1 package had stderr output: moveit_ros_warehouse
> 33 packages not processed

I see this and look closer at ws/build/moveit_ros_warehouse/CMakeFiles and cat CMakeError.log. Here is the cat:

> Performing C SOURCE FILE Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD failed with the >following output:
> Change Dir: /home/forrest/robotics/moveo_ws/ws/build/moveit_ros_warehouse/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_6c77e/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_6c77e.dir
> /build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_6c77e.dir/build
> make[1]: Entering directory '/home/forrest/robotics/moveo_ws/ws/build/moveit_ros_warehouse/CMakeFile/CMakeTmp'
> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_6c77e.dir/src.c.o
> /usr/bin/cc   -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_6c77e.dir/src.c.o   -c /home/forrest/robotics/moveo_ws/ws/build/moveit_ros_warehouse/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
> Linking C executable cmTC_6c77e
> /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_6c77e.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
> /usr/bin/cc  -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD    CMakeFiles/cmTC_6c77e.dir/src.c.o  -o cmTC_6c77e
> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_6c77e.dir/src.c.o: in function `main': src.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to` pthread_create'
> /usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `pthread_detach' /usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to` pthread_join'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_6c77e.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_6c77e] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/forrest/robotics/moveo_ws/ws/build/moveit_ros_warehouse/CMakeFile/CMakeTmp'
> make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_6c77e/fast] Error 2
>
> Source file was:
> #include <pthread.h>
>
> void* test_func(void* data)
> {
> return data;
> }
>
> int main(void)
> {
> pthread_t thread;
> pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
> pthread_detach(thread);
> pthread_join(thread, NULL);
> pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
> pthread_exit(NULL);
>
> return 0;
> }
>
> Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the >following output:
> Change Dir: /home/forrest/robotics/moveo_ws/ws/build/moveit_ros_warehouse/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_9cb30/fast && /usr/bin/make -f >CMakeFiles/cmTC_9cb30.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9cb30.dir/build
> make[1]: Entering directory '/home/forrest/robotics/moveo_ws/ws/build/moveit_ros_warehouse/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9cb30.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
> /usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o >CMakeFiles/cmTC_9cb30.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
> Linking C executable cmTC_9cb30
> /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_9cb30.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
> /usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    >CMakeFiles/cmTC_9cb30.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_9cb30  -lpthreads
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_9cb30.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_9cb30] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/forrest/robotics/moveo_ws/ws/build/moveit_ros_warehouse/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
> make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_9cb30/fast] Error 2

Is this the error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads?
I checked online and people recommend not to use -l when working with pthreads. I'm new to c and don't know much about pthreads. I also don't know where to go about finding CMakeFiles/cmTC_9cb30.dir and changing -lpthreads to -pthread

Is the error the top half that says there are 3 undefined referrences to pthread functions?

Any guidance on this would be wonderfully appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381730/colcon-build-moveit2-failure-because-of-moveit_ros_warehouse-collect2-error/) by [Daggrosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/75510/daggrosh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2021-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tried building it from source and I didn't have any error, can you share more info, which commits hash are you using for each package .? what's the output of `echo $AMENT_PREFIX_PATH` .? what's the output for the following command `apt policy ros-foxy-warehouse-ros ros-foxy-warehouse-ros-mongo` .?

---

Originally posted by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) with karma: 221 on 2021-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daggrosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/75510/daggrosh/) on 2021-07-05**:
The ament prefix path output is:
/opt/ros/foxy

The output for the apt policy is:
ros-foxy-warehouse-ros:
Installed: 2.0.1-1focal.20210601.182449
Candidate: 2.0.1-1focal.20210601.182449
Version table:
*** 2.0.1-1focal.20210601.182449 500
500 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
ros-foxy-warehouse-ros-mongo:
Installed: 2.0.2-1focal.20210618.005428
Candidate: 2.0.2-1focal.20210618.005428
Version table:
*** 2.0.2-1focal.20210618.005428 500
500 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

More information: I have built moveit2 up until the packages depending on moveit_ros_warehouse (which total 11 packages) using the --continue-on-error colcon command, so I have successfully installed warehouse_ros and warehouse_ros_mongo.

**Comment by [Daggrosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/75510/daggrosh/) on 2021-07-05**:
I have since tried to build moveit2 again in a fresh ws. Here are the exact steps, which ended with the same error:

mkdir moveit2_test
cd moveit2_test
git clone git@github.com:ros-planning/moveit2    #successful
mv moveit2 src
rosdep install -i -r --from-paths src --ignore src --rosdistro foxy -y   #successful
colcon build --event-handlers desktop_notification- status- --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release     #successful until moveit_ros_warehouse

error:
--- stderr: moveit_ros_warehouse
/usr/bin/ld: libmoveit_warehouse.so.: undefined reference to `MD5'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse_broadcast.dir/build.make:346: warehouse/moveit_warehouse_broadcast] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:189: warehouse/CMakeFiles/moveit_warehouse_broadcast.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2

I also got a stderror output for moveit_core, but it was a warning and don't think it's a big deal

**Comment by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) on 2021-07-06**:
After debugging it further, I think this's due to a bug in ament_cmake where it does prefer the system installed package rather than the source one, if you remove these packages `ros-foxy-warehouse-ros` `ros-foxy-warehouse-ros-mongo` it should pass

**Comment by [Daggrosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/75510/daggrosh/) on 2021-07-07**:
It worked! You're magic man, thanks so much